# LLVM Compile error " error: ‘vector’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type"

Tags: llvm

I am trying to compile the llvm code at the end of this post. However, I get the error below. What is wrong? Am i forgetting to include a library?

It is for a parser that works with the tool Bison.

Thanks

---

---

```
  parser.y:40:1: error: ‘vector’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
  // For 'A' and 'B'
  ^
 parser.y:42:1: error: ‘llvm’ does not name a type
  // For 'Type'
  ^
```

The file parser.y is below:

```
    %{
    #include < iostream>
    #include < cstdio>
    #include < cstdlib>
    #include < vector>
    #include < cstring>
    #include < llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h>
    #include < llvm/IR/Module.h>
    #include <llvm/IR/Function.h>
    #include "parser.h"

    extern "C" int yylex();
    //extern "C" int yyparse();
    extern "C" FILE *yyin;
    void yyerror(const char *s);


    llvm::Function *function;
    llvm::IRBuilder<> *builder;
    llvm::LLVMContext &context = llvm::getGlobalContext();
    llvm::Module module("TestModule", context);


    %}
    %token TokenId
    %token TokenNumber
    %token TokenPlus
    %token TokenMult
    %token TokenParOpen
    %token TokenParClose
    %token ty
    %token TokenComma
    %token TokenSemicolon

    //std::vector<Type *> ParamTys;
    std::vector<Type *> types;

    %union
    {
    // For 'A' and 'B'
    std::vector<llvm::Type *> *types;
    // For 'Type'
    llvm::Type *type;
    // For 'id'
    char *name;
    }
    %%**
    Function: ty TokenId TokenParOpen First_param TokenParClose                 TokenSemicolon
    {
    llvm::Constant *constant =         module.getOrInsertFunction(TokenId,llvm::ArrayType::get(types,0));
    }
    |
    First_param: ty TokenId Following_param
    {
    types.push_back(First_param);
    }
    | 
    Following_param: TokenComma ty TokenId Following_param
    {
    types.push_back(Following_param);
    }

    %%

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {



    // Syntax
    if (argc != 2)
    {
    std::cerr << "Syntax: ./main <file>\n";
    exit(1);
    }
    // Open file in 'yyin'
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!yyin)
    {
    std::cerr << "Cannot open file\n";
    exit(1);
    }
    // Parse input until there is no more
    do
    {
    yyparse();
    } while (!feof(yyin));
    // Accept
    std::cout << "Program accepted\n";
    }
    void yyerror(const char *s)
    {
    std::cerr << s << std::endl;
    exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please give more information about how you compile the file? This looks like a file for `YACC` or `Bison`, Have you ever tried to use these two tools to translate it to C/C++ file yet?